# Stolz-Cesaro Theorem, 0/0 Case

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How to prove the $0/0$ case of Stolz-Cesaro Theorem? In other words:

Given that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$$
with $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ strictly monotone, and that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1} - a_{n}}{b_{n+1} - b_{n}} = L$$ prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = L$.

Comment: You find [here](http://planetmath.org/ProofOfStolzCesaroTheorem) a proof for that theorem.

Comment: But the proof is for the case when $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = +\infty$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without loss of generality, suppose ${b_n}$ monotonically decreases. Thus $b_n\gt0$ and $b_n-b_{n+1} \gt 0$.
If $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n-a_{n+1}}{b_n-b_{n+1}}=L,$$
then for any given $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that
$$(L-\epsilon)(b_n-b_{n+1}) \lt a_n-a_{n+1} \lt (L+\epsilon)(b_n-b_{n+1})$$
for all $n \gt N$.
Let $k \gt n$ be a natural number. Summing the inequalities above, we get:
$$(L-\epsilon)\sum_{i=n}^{k}(b_i-b_{i+1}) \lt \sum_{i=n}^{k}(a_i-a_{i+1})
\lt (L+\epsilon)\sum_{i=n}^{k}(b_i-b_{i+1}),$$
i.e.,$$(L-\epsilon)(b_n-b_{k+1}) \lt a_n-a_{k+1} \lt (L+\epsilon)(b_n-b_{k+1}).$$
In this inequality, fix $n$ and let $k \to \infty$, we get
$$(L-\epsilon)b_n \le a_n \le (L+\epsilon)b_n,$$
that is, $$L-\epsilon \le \frac{a_n}{b_n} \le L+\epsilon.$$
This relation holds for all $n \gt N$, so finally $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L.$$

Comment: why u can switch the order of $\frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_n}$ to $\frac{a_{n} - a_{n+1}}{b_{n} - b_{n+1}}$

Comment: why u can assume bn monotone decreasing?

Comment: @user136266 If $(b_n)$ is increasing, let $c_n=-b_n$, then $(c_n)$ is decreasing. Apply the proof to $(c_n)$, you'll get the same conclusion for $(b_n)$.