# If $u_{n+1}\le u_n+u_n^2$ and $\sum u_n$ converges, prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(n\cdot u_n)=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Given the positive sequence $\{u_n\},n\in \mathbb{N}$ that meets the conditions:

$\boxed{1}$. $u_{n+1}\le u_n+u_n^2$

$\boxed{2}$. Exist the constant $\text{M} >0$ so that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n u_k\le \text{M},\, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

> Prove that $$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(n\cdot u_n)=0$$

I think that we can use the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem, 0/0 Case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599204/stolz-cesaro-theorem-0-0-case), but I haven't found how.

Comment: Since there are no functions do calculate derivatives of, L'Hospital is out of the question...

Comment: @5xum: the Cesaro-Stoltz theorem is the discrete equivalent of De L'Hopital theorem, probably the OP means that.

Comment: It might help to think a little bit about why you need both conditions. Any positive decreasing sequence, say $u_n=1/n$, satisfies the first property, yet $\lim n (1/n)=1$. On the other hand, the infinite sum being finite is also not enough, because you could have a sequence which is "usually small" except that it "spikes up" occasionally, something like $u_n=1/n$ when $n=2^k$ for some $k$ and $2^{-n}$ otherwise. So somehow, if the sum is finite and $u_n$ is "eventually almost constant", you get $u_n \ll 1/n$ for large $n$.

Comment: @Ian I have a small question. Could you explain your ideas clearer in sentence "something like $u_n=1/n$ when $n=2k$ for some $k$ and $2^{−n}$ otherwise. So somehow, if the sum is finite and un is "eventually almost constant", you get $u_n \ll 1/n$ for large $n$?"
 Because my English is not good, so I can not understand your ideas exactly. :)

Comment: @DDK Rephrasing: the first property is not enough to get your conclusion because any positive decreasing sequence will satisfy it, yet certainly there are plenty of positive decreasing sequences $u_n$ where $n u_n$ does not converge to zero. The second property is not enough to get your conclusion because I can make a convergent series where for "most" $n$, $u_n$ is much less than $1/n$, but nevertheless for infinitely many $n$, $u_n=1/n$. Then $n u_n$ will have at least two limit points, namely $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @DDK (Cont.) By spacing out the $n$ where $u_n=1/n$ exponentially far apart, I can make the resulting series actually converge. (The resulting series is more or less two geometric series interwoven together.) But my second example is forbidden by your first property, which implies that if at some point $u_n$ is very small, then it will take "a lot of steps" for $u_n$ to become large again.

Comment: @DDK This "lot of steps to become large" issue is used in robjohn's answer, but in reverse: he argues that if $u_n$ is relatively large then actually $u_{n-k}$ had to have been relatively large as well.

Answer (score 16):

Since
$$
u_{n+1}\le u_n+u_n^2\tag{1}
$$
we can apply the monotonically increasing function $\frac{x}{1+x}$ to  both sides of $(1)$ to get
$$
\frac{u_{n+1}}{1+u_{n+1}}\le\frac{u_n+u_n^2}{1+u_n+u_n^2}\le u_n\tag{2}
$$
Suppose that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}nu_n=\varepsilon\gt0\tag{3}
$$
This means that for infinitely many $n$, we have
$$
u_n\ge\frac\varepsilon{2n}\tag{4}
$$
For $m=\frac2\varepsilon n$, we have $u_n\ge\frac1m$, then by $(2)$, $u_{n-1}\ge\frac{\frac1m}{1+\frac1m}=\frac1{m+1}$ and by induction
$$
u_n\ge\frac1m\implies u_{n-k}\ge\frac1{m+k}\tag{5}
$$
thus,
$$
\sum_{k=n/2}^nu_k\ge\frac{n/2}{m+n/2}=\frac\varepsilon{\varepsilon+4}\tag{6}
$$
Since there are infinitely many $n$ that satisfy $(4)$, there are infinitely many intervals $\left[\frac n2,n\right]$ so that $(6)$ is true. However, then the sum of $u_n$ would diverge. Therefore, $(3)$ must be false and we must have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}nu_n=0\tag{7}
$$

Comment: Elegant .I'd seen this problem before  and couldn't remember how to solve it but I was sure that working back  from large n would be  the way.

Comment: Very nice. Well presented too.

Comment: The core here I feel is the use of $\frac{x}{1+x}$; what brought you to that idea?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: actually, I started by solving $u_n^2+u_n-u_{n+1}=0$ for $u_n$. The solution is $$u_n= \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4u_{n+1}}}2= \frac{2u_{n+1}}{1+\sqrt{1+4u_{n+1}}}\ge \frac{u_{n+1}}{1+u_{n+1}}$$ Then, seeing the final result, I knew I could avoid the whole quadratic formula sidetrack by using $\frac{x}{1+x}$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: then, I noticed that $u_{n+1}\le u_n(1+u_n)$ has two cases: $u_{n+1}\le u_n$ and $u_{n+1}\ge u_n$ where $u_{n+1}\le u_n(1+u_{n+1})$. Either one gives $u_n\ge\frac{u_{n+1}}{1+u_{n+1}}$.

Comment: @robjohn Could you please see what could go wrong here? If $\lim n \cdot u_n = \epsilon >0$. Then, there are infinite number of terms of $u_n$ satisfying : $n \cdot u_n \ge \epsilon/2 \implies u_n >\frac{\epsilon}{2n}$ for an infinite number of terms. Since, $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is a divergent series means $\sum u_n$ is also divergent, a contradiction.

Comment: First, we are not given that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nu_n=\epsilon\gt0$; we have $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}nu_n=\varepsilon\gt0$. Given that, an infinite number of terms so that $u_n\gt\frac\epsilon{2n}$ is not good enough to ensure divergence. Consider $u_n=\frac1n$ if $n=k^2$ for some $k$ and $2^{-n}$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the beginning of the solution should look like this:

Write
$$n\cdot u_n=\frac{u_n}{\frac1n}$$

To apply the Cesaro-Stoltz theorem, let's try to calculate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{\frac1{n+1}-\frac1n}$$
but, applying the first condition,
$$\left|\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{\frac1{n+1}-\frac1n}\right|\le n(n+1)u_n^2$$

But I confess that I'm stuck now, since we sholud show now that $n(n+1)u_n^2\to 0$ and I don't know how. Perhaps Cauchy Schwartz inequality combined with the condition 2?

Comment: (+1) So we get that if $L=\lim n u_n$ exists, it is less than its square, so $L\leq 0$ (and that is fine since it implies $L=0$ as wanted) or $L\geq 1$, that contradicts the summability. So we only need to prove that the limit exists.

Comment: If the limit can be shown to exists then we don't need Cesaro-Stoltz to conclude that the limit is $0$. A simple comparison to the harmonic series is enough.

Comment: @Winther: you are clearly right.

Answer (score 2):

Define $(p_n)$ and $(a_n)$ by

$$ p_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1+u_k) \qquad\text{and}\qquad a_n = \frac{u_n}{p_n}. $$

We make the following observations:

- $\boxed{1}$ implies that $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$. That is, $(a_n)$ is positive and non-increasing.
- Since $a_n \leq u_n$, $\boxed{2}$ implies that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$. Then a standard argument tells that
  $$ \bbox[border:1px dotted navy; color:navy; padding:5px;]{ \lim_{n\to\infty} n a_n = 0. } \tag{1} $$
  Indeed, monotonicity of $(a_n)$ yields $\frac{1}{2} n a_n \leq \sum_{k=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}^{n} a_k $, which vanishes as $n \to \infty$ by $\boxed{2}$.
- By the inequality $1+x \leq e^x$, we get $p_n \leq e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} u_k}$. So, $\boxed{2}$ implies $(p_n)$ is bounded above. Moreover, $(p_n)$ is non-decreasing. Hence,
  $$ \bbox[border:1px dotted navy; color:navy; padding:5px;]{ (p_n) \text{ converges.} } \tag{2} $$

Combining $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ altogether, we conclude:

$$ nu_n = na_n \cdot p_n \to 0 $$

Comment: Wow! This is EXTREMELY clever.  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

First observe that $\lim_n u_n =0$ because of hypothesis 2. Thus
$$
{n \over 2}u_n  
$$
and
$$
\left(n-\lfloor n/2\rfloor\right)u_n
$$
have the same limit (if any) as $n\to\infty$. Also, the difference   $\sum_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n u_k- 
\left(n-\lfloor n/2\rfloor \right)u_n$
 is $\sum_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n (u_k-u_n)$,
which is (by hypothesis 1.) at least $
-\sum_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n u^2_k$.
Because $\lim_n \sum_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n u_k=0$ by hypothesis 2. and $\left(n-\lfloor n/2\rfloor \right)u_n$ is nonnegative, it suffices to show that $\lim_n\sum_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n u^2_k =0$. But this last sum is nonnegative and at most $M\cdot\sup_{k\ge\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}u_k$, which tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ because $\lim_k u_k=0$ as already noted.

Comment: I don't understand how you're controlling the sum of the squares. I'm also not sure that $u_k - u_n \geq -u_k^2$ always holds; what if $u_k$ is very small at some point, and then makes its way back up gradually?

Comment: Indeed the lower bound on the difference should be $-\sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} u_j^2$, and without the minus sign this latter sum of squares is at most $\sum_{j=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^n\left(j-\lfloor n/2\rfloor\right) u_j^2$. This goes to $0$ provided $j u_j$ is bounded above by a constant...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I am sorry for typo I could have, cause English is not my native language. And this is a solution of one of my friends.

Given arbitrary small number $\alpha>0$.

Supposed that the positive sequence $\{u_n\}$ has infinitely many term $u_n$ which is larger than or equal to $\alpha$.

Hence, we obtain $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} u_k=+\infty$ which is opposite to the hypothesis $\boxed{2}$.

So, the sequence $\displaystyle\{u_n\}$ only has limited term which is larger than $\alpha$ and has infinitely many term which is less than $\alpha$. However, $\alpha$ is a arbitrary positive number, we can implies that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}u_n=0\tag{1}$

Hence, the sequence $\displaystyle\{n\cdot u_n\}$ either has limit $0$ or has limit $\alpha>0$.

---

- Supposed that the sequence $\displaystyle\{n\cdot u_n\}$ descends to $+\infty$

Take a arbitrary number $b>\text M$. In this case, there exists a natural number $\text N_0$ so that $\displaystyle n\cdot u_n>b,\forall n>\text N_0$.

On the other hand, considering the number $\displaystyle\frac{pb}{\text N_0+p-1}$, which $p$ is a natural number. It's easily seen that $\displaystyle\frac{pb}{\text N_0+p-1}>\text M$ if $p$ is large enough.

So, if $p$ is large enough, we obtain: $$u_1+u_2+...+u_{\text N_0}+...+u_{\text N_0+p-1}>\frac{b}{\text N_0}+\frac{b}{\text N_0+1}+...+\frac{b}{\text N_0 +p-1}>\frac{pb}{\text N_0+p-1}>\text M$$ which is opposite to hypothesis of this problem.
**So, this case muse be eliminated.**

---

- Supposed that the sequence $\displaystyle\{n\cdot u_n\}$ has limit $a$: That means when $n$ descends to $+\infty$, term $u_n$ descends to $\dfrac an$. But  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a}{n}$ diverges, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} u_k$ descends to $+\infty$, which is opposite to hypothesis of this problem. **So, this case must also be eliminated.**

---

Conclusion, there only has a case that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}n.u_n=0$

Comment: You say: "Hence, the sequence $\displaystyle\{n\cdot u_n\}$ either has limit $0$ or has limit $\alpha>0$." Why does the sequence have to have a limit at all? Where did you use the hypothesis that $u_{n+1}\le u_n+u_n^2$? [Ian's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416018/if-u-n1-le-u-nu-n2-and-sum-u-n-converges-prove-that-lim-limits-n-t/1416356#comment2885225_1416018) explains why this hypothesis is necessary.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you. I will ask the owner of this answer. Please wait.

Comment: @robjohn I have ask the owner of this solution. And his answer is:
If the sequence $u_n$ doesn't meet hypothesis 1, that means there will happen the case $u_{n+1}>u_n+u_n^2=u_n(1+u_n)>u_n,\forall n$. In this case, the sequence $u_n$ must be increase, which doesn't meet hypothesis 2.

Comment: That is not correct. The negation of $u_{n+1}\le u_n+u_n^2$ **for all** $\boldsymbol{n}$ is that $u_{n+1}\gt u_n+u_n^2$ **for some** $\boldsymbol{n}$.  It is not the case that we are assuming $u_{n+1}\gt u_n+u_n^2$ for all $n$, so it doesn't negate hypothesis 2.

Comment: You're right that $u_n$ must converge to zero, but that does not mean that $n u_n$ must converge at all. The second example in my first comment on the answer uses a $u_n$ where $n u_n$ has two limit points.