# Series expansion of harmonic numbers derivation.

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

I can get,

$$h_n \approx \ln n+\gamma$$

By, saying

$$\frac{h_{n}-h_{n-1}}{n-(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n}$$

Then letting $h_n=h(n)$ be continuous and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. So that,

$$h'(n) \approx \frac{1}{n}$$

And thus,

$$h_n \approx \ln n+C$$

Where we will let $C$ give us the best approximation as $n \to \infty$ that is,

$$C=\lim_{n \to \infty} (h_n-\ln n)$$

What about the other terms, I'm curious to see how they are derived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_n=H_n-(\ln n+\gamma)$ with $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ and evaluate the following limit by using the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599204/stolz-cesaro-theorem-0-0-case) ($\ast/0$ case),
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{1/(n+1)-1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1/(n+1)-\ln(1+1/n)}{1/(n+1)-1/n}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Hence $H_n=\ln(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}+o(1/n)$.

More terms can be found in a similar way (a [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) involves the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)). Another method to find the asymptotic expansion of the harmonic numbers employs [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{H_{n} - \ln\pars{n}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} +
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 \over 2} + \ln\pars{2 \over 3} + \cdots + \ln\pars{n - 1 \over n}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{1 +
\sum_{k = 2}^{n}\bracks{{1 \over k} + \ln\pars{k - 1 \over k}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{1 +
\sum_{k = 2}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{{1 \over k} + {1 \over t - k}}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
1 + \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over k + 2} - {1 \over k + 2 - t}}\,\dd t
= 1 + \int_{0}^{1}\pars{H_{1 - t} - H_{1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}H_{1 - t}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{-\,\totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2 - t}}}{t} + \gamma}\,\dd t
= \bbx{\gamma}
\end{align}