# Is the "General" Stolz-Césaro Theorem true for the case $0/0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

**Stolz-Césaro Theorem:** let $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ be real sequences.
$\ \ \ \ $ $\infty/\infty$ **case:** if $y_n$ is monotone and unbounded, then (as shown [here](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Enagy/snippets/stolz-cesaro.pdf))
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Delta x_n}{\Delta y_n} \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Delta x_n}{\Delta y_n}.$$
$\ \ \ \ $ $0/0$ **case:** if $x_n, y_n\to 0$, then we have (as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599204/stolz-cesaro-theorem-0-0-case)) that
$$\frac{\Delta x_n}{\Delta y_n} \to L \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{x_n}{y_n}\to L$$
(where the statement "$\Delta x_n/\Delta y_n \to L$" may be false if the limit doesn't exist.)

---

Observe how the statement for the $0/0$ case is weaker. It is natural to wonder if the following is true:

$\ \ \ \ $ **Stronger $0/0$ case:** given the real sequences $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ so that $x_n,y_n\to 0$, we have that
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Delta x_n}{\Delta y_n} \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Delta x_n}{\Delta y_n}.$$

Is the statement above true? If so, how could one prove it? If not, what is a counter-example?